# Django-Nonrel AbstractUser Permissions

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, permissions, django-nonrel

I am working on a project and I have decided to use Google App Engine for hosting (Django-nonrel). The website will have multiple types of users (inheriting from AbstractUser), and I want to be able to create permissions to control what a user can see/do. Since the native Django permissions do not work on Nonrel, I tried using [permission_backend_nonrel](https://github.com/django-nonrel/django-permission-backend-nonrel), however it only works if you use the standard User model.

I have spent lots of time searching for how others have gotten permissions to work on Nonrel and AbstractUser, but have not found anything. It seems like I should give up on getting permissions to work and just create fields within the user models to replicate permissions. For example, if I want only some users to have the ability to change their email address, then I could do:

accounts\models.py

```
class UserProfile(AbstractUser):

  address = models.CharField(max_length=40)
  can_change_email = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

customers\models.py

```
class CustomerProfile(UserProfile):

  company = models.BooleanField(max_length=40)
```

In this scenario I could set 'can_change_email' and control this behavior in the views for UserProfile.

I would prefer to use the built-in permission system, but running out of ideas. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you might have better luck creating separate one-to-one models to signify the difference between your users. Django expects you to have a single user model.

Another option is to use the normal User model and create proxy models that reflect the changes you want to have between users.

The first way:

```
class CustomerProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

The second way:

```
class CustomerProfile(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```